# How to make this for loop delete the dictionary at any index?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

How would I make this code for the deleting of Player dictionarys in a PlayerID list remove a dictionary at any index?

```
for index, Player in enumerate(PlayerID):
if Player['ID'] == SearchID:
    PlayerID.pop(index)
    print("The user with ID", SearchID, ", has been deleted")
    break
else:
    print("The ID provided does not exist.")
```

Whenever I have multiple dictionaries stored on this list, all with different ID's, it only seems to say that the ID associated with the first index exists, and the others prompt the error message as seen in the "else" statement

Comment: Could somebody please help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the list as you iterate, that is not a good idiom

You can use the else statement on for loop: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

I asume your list is something like: `[{'id':3}{'id':7}{'id':6}]`

```
def remove_player(player_id, player_list):
    for idx in xrange(0, len(player_list)):
        if player_id == player_list[idx]['id']
            player_list.pop(idx)
            print("The user with ID", player_id, ", has been deleted")
            break
    else:
        print("The ID provided does not exist.")
```

Note that the else is only executed when the loop is finished normaly (without break)